# GUI button problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want create a GUI for my python script.

I managed to define a background and now i would like to add my buttons but problem is here. Like you can see on the following screen

[image]

Here's the portion of my code where i define the image

```py
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparent", True)
root.config(bg='systemTransparent')
NewAccountImg=tk.PhotoImage(file="NewAccountImg.gif")
background_image=tk.PhotoImage(file="fond.png")
background_label=tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

And

```py
root.newaccount = tk.Button(root,text="New Account",command=partial(Set_Acc_and_Hide,root),image=NewAccountImg)
```

How can I make my button transparent?

Comment: `tkinter.Button` does not support transparent background.  Try using `Canvas.create_image(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 how can that help me résolve my button image problem then ? I mean, create à canvas ok but what then ? My button still wont have an image

Comment: As I said you can't use `Button()` if you want transparent background.  Try using `Canvas.create_image(...)` to simulate a button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PIL library for image.

PIL supports transparency.

Here is an example:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGBA', (100, 100), (255, 0, 0, 0))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.ellipse((25, 25, 75, 75), fill=(255, 0, 0))

img.save('test1.gif', 'GIF', transparency=0)
# this generates gif of red colored circle with white background(transparent background).

img.save('test2.gif', 'GIF', transparency=1)
# this generates gif of white colored circle(transparent circle) with red background.
```